# How to write a query to retrieve distinct nodes from firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get three distinct nodes while making a query in android for pagination purpose.I have nodes tree as follows

[image: tree of nodes]

I build a logic to get three nodes by making the query as

```
Query q =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        .getReference()
        .child("testting")
        .orderByKey().startAt(starting_point)
        .limitToFirst(3);
```

And in the  above code `starting_point` is key of the node from where I want to get the **next** three nodes ***excluding*** the `starting_point` node. But as I have given query to start from `starting_point` node, it is repeating point node in result.

Image to reflect the result:

[image: image to show that starting node is repeated in result]

So please guide how to make query to get next nodes **excluding** starting_point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database API only supports querying to so-called inclusive ranges. There is no way to exclude the first (or the last) node from the query results. This means that you'll have to remove the overlapping item client-side. This typically means that you compare the key of the first result to the last key you've previously seen, and exclude it if the keys are the same.

This is by the way one of the points that the query API of the new Cloud Firestore database addresses. It has explicit `startAfter` and `endBefore` methods that allow exclusive range queries.

Comment: Sir! I have implemented a logic on client side to add only those nodes to data list collection if  node id is distinct (Problem is solved).But How can I come to know that   there is  no node after  a  node  having  the specific id ?.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correct. If there is no node after a key, then a query starting at that key would give only one result: that key itself.